# How to efficiently copy a slice into a Rust VecDeque

Tags: rust, slice, deque

I'm handling byte input in a streaming fashion like so:

```rust
pub struct CharQueue<R: Read> {
    reader: R,
    deque: VecDeque<u8>,
    buf: [u8;1024],
}
```

```rust
self.deque.reserve_exact(bytes_read);
for i in 0..bytes_read {
    self.deque.push_back(self.buf[i]);
}
```

In profiling, it appears that `VecDeque::cap()` is a major contributor to runtime. This is surprising because it does almost nothing but return a variable (and branch, I guess):

```rust
fn cap(&self) -> usize {
    if mem::size_of::<T>() == 0 {
        // For zero sized types, we are always at maximum capacity
        MAXIMUM_ZST_CAPACITY
    } else {
        self.buf.capacity()
    }
}
```

So it must be getting called an enormous number of times (which it would be, if it's getting called inside `push_back()`, which makes well enough sense in hindsight).

I'm wondering if there's a way to copy this entire buffer into the queue in one go, so the capacity only has to be checked and incremented once. `.reserve_exact()` skips the intermediate allocations, but not the checks and increments. `.append()` is kind of along these lines, but I'd have to consume the buffer to transform it into another VecDeque first, which I don't want to do because I want to re-use it. What I really want is something like `push_back_slice()` that just takes a slice, increments the queue length/does any required allocations *once*, and then copies each element of the slice directly into the available space without mutating or consuming it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that you run release version? It is quite surprising that this function doesn't inlined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VecDeque` implements the `Extend` trait, allowing you to add all items from an iterator to the collection without performing repeated allocations or checks. With your code, that should look like this:

```
self.deque.extend(bytes_read.iter().copied());
```

Comment: For your convenience: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.extend